# Qt Creator libssl-1_1-x64.dll was not found when open qml file

Tags: windows, qt, qml, qt-creator

Windows 10,
Qt Creator 9.0.2

When open some qml file I get the error:

```
qmlplugindump.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because libssl-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK
```

But the folder `QtCreator/bin` **contains** the file. How to fix that correctly?

I can add the path to the PATH env variable, but it is strange to do it manually.

Comment: Is this a standalone install of QtCreator? If you intend to do Qt development, Qt, QML, C++, etc. You should get a full Qt install. A bare QtCreator install is, essentially the editor/IDE parts only, and, it will not function correctly unless if you can point it to a Qt install and/or a Qt kit.

Comment: @StephenQuan yes, it is standalone install of QtCreator. Thank you for note about the standalone install is not correct

Answer (score 0):

qmlplugindump.exe is part of the Qt installation, not Qt Creator, so it looks like libssl is missing in your Qt installation (next to the qmlplugindump.exe)